# Return address with sendmail says '<user>@localhost.localdomain'

Tags: linux, sendmail

I don't know why, but the return address of an email sent through `sendmail` using `mailx` says `<user>@localhost.localdomain` even though I have set `LOCAL_DOMAIN` to `jwd.sytes.net`. It works when I put `192.168.0.3 jwd.sytes.net` as the first line of `/etc/hosts`, but then it isn't getting the real IP of `jwd.sytes.net` when someone types `ping jwd.sytes.net`. Does anyone have any idea of how to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to modify `submit.mc` (`submit.cf`) too?

Comment: It provides a suggestion - an answer in "it _MAY_ help" mode.

Comment: No, I haven't. How should I edit it? I looked at the file, and nothing jumped out at me as being what needed to be changed.